# Swift: joined() for Array of NSAttributedString?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

In Swift, you can join an `Array` of `String` like so:

```
let a = ["fee", "fi", "fo", "fum"]
print(a.joined(separator: " ")) // -> "fee fi fo fum"
```

How can I join an `Array` of `NSAttributedString` like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extension adds the ability to join an `Array` of `NSAttributedString`, as you would with `String`s.

```
extension Array where Element: NSAttributedString {
  func joined(separator: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString {
    guard let firstElement = first else { return NSAttributedString() }

    return dropFirst()
      .reduce(into: NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: firstElement)) { collector, element in
        collector.append(separator)
        collector.append(element)
      }
  }

  func joined(separator: String = "") -> NSAttributedString {
    joined(separator: NSAttributedString(string: separator))
  }
}
```